# firefox 42 mousewheel began zooming instead of scrolling

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

Today something strange happened. The mouse wheel no longer scrolls but zooms instead. How can I correct this?

Windows 7
Firefox 42

Comment: Is your <ctrl> key stuck down?

Comment: @davidPostill yes and not. Not in a physical way but it seems that in a software way, at least for windows 7, it was.

Comment: Did you try restarting Firefox? You can also try pressing <ctrl> (both left and right), <alt> and <shift> (left and right) a few times each. This can release a "logical" stuck key" from this group of keys.

Comment: @DavidPostill yup. i even got into about:config and fooled around with a lot of mousewheel configurations. It was a windows 7 glitch. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by itself just by turning off the laptop and turning it on again.

Comment: Ahh, the universal solution.  Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In another day, you will be able to accept your own answer, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @fixer1234 "the universal solution" yes indeed.